# Linux console equivalent to gui copy/paste file/directory scenario

Tags: linux, console, command-line-interface, copy-paste

How to simply recreate copy/paste functionality like in gui environments?

My typical scenario for copying file/directory in Linux console is:

```
cp source_path target_path
```

Sometimes paths are relative, sometimes absolute, but I need to provide them both. It works, but there are situations where I would like to recreate scenario from gui which is:

```
1. go to source directory
2. copy file/directory
3. go to target directory
4. paste file/directory
```

I imagine something like

```
cd source_directory_path
copy_to_stash source_name
cd target_directory_path
paste_from_stash [optional_new_target_name]
```

I know that there is a xclip app, but a documentation says that it copies content of a file, not a file handle. Also, I can use `$OLDPWD` variable and expand it when I copy file, but this is not a solution without some cumbersome.

Is there some simple, general, keyboard only, not awkward to use equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also asked the same question on superuser and answer that I've received is good enough for me.

In short: two additional scripts and temporary variable to hold intermediate value.

Below is a code and link to original answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
# source me with one of:
# source [file]
# . [file]

# Initialize
sa_file=

sa(){
# Fuction to save a file in the current PWD
if [[ -e "$PWD/$1" ]]; then
    sa_file=$PWD/$1
    echo "Saved for later: $sa_file"
else
    echo "Error: file $PWD/$1 does not exist"
fi
}


pa(){
# Paste if file exists, to $1 if exists
if [[ -e "$sa_file" ]]; then
    if [[ $1 ]]; then
        cp -v "$sa_file" "$1"
    else
        cp -v "$sa_file" .
    fi
else
    echo "Error: file $sa_file does not exist, could not copy"
fi
}
```

https://superuser.com/a/1405953/614464

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it your only option is to write a script to do all of those steps. You could easily implement the clipboard functionality by copying the file to the /tmp directory before copying again from it.

This should work as intended.
Usage: script [from] [to]

```
filename=$(basename "$0")
tmpfile=/tmp/$filename.$RANDOM
cd $(dirname "$0")
cp $tmpfile $filename
cd $(dirname "$1")
cp $tmpfile $(basename "$1")
```

Answer (score -1):

One option: you can either copy-paste the filename using mouse, using copy-paste feature from your terminal emulator (e.g. Konsole or GNOME Terminal), but this: 1) requires a GUI since the terminal emulator software run in GUI; 2) well, requires a mouse.

Another option: utilize shell tab completion. You still need to type the filename, but not all of it.

Third option, and this is closer to how you work in a GUI file explorer: use a TUI-based file explorer, e.g. the dual-pane style Midnight Commander. You can use arrow keys (if you turn on the Lynx-like motion setting, which is very recommended) to quickly navigate the directory tree. Then select files using the `Insert`, `+`, `-`, or `*` keys, then copy/move files from one pane to another. It's very convenient. In fact half of the time I spend in CLI, I spend in MC.

Comment: I wanted to use only keyboard and pure console without additional managers (I would like to have additional entries in *sh history)